# Django- how to add another field to a table displayed in a web page

Tags: python, html, django

I am debugging a Django project, and want to display another field from the database in a table on the webpage.

The Django HTML for the table as it's currently displayed in the webpage is:

```
<table class="multisection pipeline left">
        <tr class="sub-summary">
             <th colspan="4"><a href="?detailed_status={{detailed_status}}"><h3 class="p-l-sm">{{detailed_status_str}}</h3></a></th>
             {% if total_i %}<th>Initial exc VAT: {{total_i|money:"£"}}</th>{% endif %}
             {% if total_u %}<th>Latest exc VAT: {{total_u|money:"£"}}</th>{% else %}
             <th></th>
             {% endif %}
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="multisection pipeline left m-b-xl">
        <tr class="summary">
            <th style="width: 3em;"></th>
            {% for field in fields %}
                <th class="text-sm p-l-sm p-t-sm p-b-sm" style="width:{{widths|getval:forloop.counter0}}">
                {% if field.1 %}
                    {% if sort == field.0 and not reverse %}
                        <a href="?sort=-{{field.0}}&detailed_status={{detailed_status}}">{{field.0}}</a>
                    {% else %}
                        <a href="?sort={{field.0}}&detailed_status={{detailed_status}}">{{field.0}}</a>
                    {% endif %}
                {% else %}
                    {{field.0}}
                {% endif %}
                </th>
                {# Make all have the same number of columns (8) #}
                {% if forloop.last %}
                    {% for i in ',,,,,,,,' %}
                        {% if forloop.counter|add:forloop.parentloop.counter0 < 11 %}
                            <th>&nbsp;</th>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% if detailed_status == "ds4"|ds %}
                        <th></th>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% with user.employee.full_name|is:'Nick Ross' as summary_link %}

        {% for project in projects %}
            <tr data-project-id="{{project.id}}" class="{% cycle 'odd' 'even' %}{% if project.office == 2 %} col{% endif %}">
                {% with initial_details=project.initial_details survey=project.survey  %}
                    {# Open lightbox #}
                    <td>
                        {% if user.is_superuser %}
                            <a class="gallery-loader" data-project-id="{{project.id}}"><i class="icon info"></i></a>

                            {% if forloop.first and first_table %}
                                <div id="iframe_gallery_wrap">

                                    <a href="#p1" class="gallery">
                                        <div id="p1">
                                            <iframe class="lightbox-content" src="{% url 'projects:description' project.id %}report/" width="1200" height="800" id="p1" style="border:none;" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="#p2" class="gallery">
                                        <div id="p2">
                                            <iframe class="lightbox-content" src="{% url 'projects:survey' project.id %}report/" width="1200" height="800" id="p1" style="border:none;" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="#p3" class="gallery">
                                        <div id="p3">
                                            <iframe class="lightbox-content" src="{% url 'projects:preconcept_notes' project.id %}report/" width="1200" height="800" id="p1" style="border:none;" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="#p4" class="gallery">
                                        <div id="p4">
                                            <iframe class="lightbox-content" src="{% url 'projects:concept' project.id %}report/" width="1200" height="800" id="p1" style="border:none;" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="#p5" class="gallery">
                                        <div id="p5">
                                            <iframe class="lightbox-content" src="{% url 'projects:handover' project.id %}report/" width="1200" height="800" id="p1" style="border:none;" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endif %}

                    </td>
                    {# Standard columns #}
                    {% with project.team as team %}

                    <td><a href="{% if summary_link %}{% url 'projects:summary' project.id %}{% else %}{% url 'projects:details' project.id %}{% endif %}">{{project.project_name}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{project.town|xor}}</td>
                    <td>{{project.postcode}}</td>
                    <td>{{project.client.full_name_a|xor}}</td>
                    {# Status-specific columns #}
                    {% if detailed_status == "ds1"|ds or detailed_status == "ds2"|ds %} {# New project leads #}
                        <td>{{project.created|date:"d/m/y"}}</td>
                        <td>{{initial_details.site_visit.date|date:"d/m/y"}}</td>
                        <td>{{initial_details.discussed_budget|money:'£'|xor}}</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    {% elif detailed_status == "ds3"|ds %} {# CDI Sent #}
                        <td>{{project.cdi.sent|date:"d/m/y"}}</td>
                        <td>{{initial_details.discussed_budget_updated|money:"£"|xor}}</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    {% elif detailed_status == "ds4"|ds %} {# CDI Signed #}
                        <td>{{team|getval:'Designer'|xor}}</td>
                        <td>{{project.budget_overview.current_exc_vat|money:"£"|xor}}</td>
                        <td>{{project.survey.meeting.date|date:"d/m/y"}}</td>
                        <td>{% for emp in project.survey.get_surveyors %}{{emp}}, {% endfor %}</td>
                        <td>{{initial_details.estimated_start|date:"m/Y"}}</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    {% elif detailed_status == "ds5"|ds %} {# Survey completed #}
                        <td>{{team|getval:'Designer'|xor}}</td>
                        <td>{{project.budget_overview.updated_exc_vat|money:"£"|xor}}</td>
                        <td>{{initial_details.preconcept_meeting.date|date:"d/m/y"}}</td>
                        <td>{{initial_details.first_presentation.presentation_date|date:"d/m/y"}}</td>
                        <td>{{initial_details.estimated_start|date:"m/Y"}}</td>
                    {% elif detailed_status == "ds6"|ds %} {# Tendering/costing drawings #}
                        <td>{{team|getval:'Designer'|xor}}</td>
                        <td>{{project.budget_overview.updated_exc_vat|money:"£"|xor}}</td>
                        <td>{{initial_details.estimated_start|date:"m/Y"}}</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    {% elif detailed_status == "ds7"|ds %} {# Post presentation #}
                        <td>{{team|getval:'Designer'|xor}}</td>
                        <td>{{project.budget_overview.updated_exc_vat|money:"£"|xor}}</td>
                        <td>{{project.chance}}{% if project.chance %}%{% endif %}</td>
                        <td>{{initial_details.last_presentation.date|date:"d/m/y"}}</td>
                        <td>{{initial_details.estimated_start|date:"m/Y"}}</td>
                    {% else %}
                        {# Standard-ish columns #}
                        <td>{{team|getval:'Architect'|xor}}</td>
                        <td>{{project.budget_overview.updated_exc_vat|money:"£"|xor}}</td>
                        <td>{{project.live_date|date:"d/m/y"}}</td>
                        <td>{{initial_details.desired_start|date:"d/m/y"}}</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    {% endif %}
                    <!--ERF(09/11/2016 @ 1540) Add an 'elif' for the site manager (ds9 is the 'Live Project' table) -->
                    {% if detailed_status == "ds9"|ds %}
                        <td>{{team|getval:'Site manager'|xor}}</td>
                        <!--td>{{project.site_manager}}</td-->
                    {% endif %}

                        {% if user.is_staff or user.is_superuser %}
                            <td>
                                <a class="delete double-check m-l-xl" data-view-url="{% url 'projects:delete' project.id %}"><img class="icon" src="{% static "img/bin.png" %}"></a>
                            </td>
                        {% endif %}
                        <td data-view-url="{% url 'projects:update_detailed_status' project.id %}" style="width:10em;">
                            {{detailed_status_changer.visible_fields.0}}
                        </td>
                    {% endwith %}

                {% endwith %}

            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endwith %}

    </table>
```

and this is currently showing a table with the following column headings:

Project name, Town, Postcode, Contact Name

These column heading are fields belonging to the Class `Project`, which is defined in the `models.py` file:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    ...
    ds2 = 20
    ...
    ds9 = 120
    ...
    ds13 = 200

    DETAILED_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ...
        ds9, 'Live project'),
        ...
    )

    # Several form fields added here, e.g. 
    employees = models.ManyToManyField(Employee, through=ProjectEmployee)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

    # Several 'def's here, e.g.
    def team(self):
        employees = self.assigned.all()
        ...
        sm = [person for person in employees if person.role==Role.SM]
        ...
        return{
            ...
            'Site manager': sm[0].employee.first_name if sm else '',
            ...
        }

    # Several `@property` definitions here, e.g.
    @property
    def estimated_compeltion(self):
        ...
```

I want to display the `Site manager` field from the database in the table on the webpage- I tried adding it to the `Python` code as shown above, but this hasn't made a difference to what is displayed on the webpage, even though that appears to be exactly the same way that all of the other fields from the database are displayed.

What am I missing here? I would expect the Django HTML to display every field that I am telling it to in the Python code, since I am using `forloop`s to get the fields... Why is it that I can't see the 'Site manager' field that I've added to the code in the table on the HTML web page?

Answer (score 0):

In your `<td/>` you are using `project.site_manager`

It seems though that your `Project` model doesn't have such a field, that's why nothing is shown.

Maybe you could create a getter for `project_manager` in your `Project` class like so :

```
def get_site_manager(self):
    sm = [person for person in self.assigned.all() if person.role==Role.SM]
    return sm[0].employee.first_name if sm else ''
```

And use it in your template as such :

```
<td>{{project.get_site_manager()}}</td>
```